# JPQL Special Query

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpql

I have two entity bean :

```
@Entity
public class User {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();

   //SOME OTHER CLASS VARIABLES
   //GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

and my Comment class is like this :

```
@Entity
public class Comment {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;

   private String title;
   private String content;

   @ManyToOne
   private User user

   //SOME OTHER CLASS VARIABLES
   //GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

now I know that I can get the User Object from session and set the user for my comment like this in order to be able to use the join feature in JPA:

```
commentObject.setUser(TheSessionGrabedUserObject/UserObjectWhichHasFetchedFromDbUsingUserId);
```

but as long as I have the userId for my user Object I do not need to do this.
I'm looking for a way to insert this foreignKey into my comment table without getting the User Object from session or maybe query to database to fetch it first !

how I'm gonna do it using JPQL ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `entityManager.getReference()` method. In your case:

```
entityManager.getReference(User.class, userId);
```

This will not perform any DB query, but will give you a `User` instance with only the ID populated, and you can pass that to `commentObject.setUser()`.

Comment: what do you mean by It doesn't perform any db query so how it fetch the data from the database thou ? I should query to db to fetch the user from database even if In the behalf of itself ...

Comment: `getReference()` doesn't need to perform a DB query to create an instance with an ID only. That's sufficient since the `commentObject` only needs the user ID. Give it a try.